# Git push not working in visual studio 2015

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

My visual studio 2015 works fine with Git connecting to BitBucket.
However when connecting to a private Gitlab server, I have a weird problem:
 - I can clone a repo from the gitlab server via the IDE (Team explorer). I can fetch/pull, put whenever I try to sync a local commit to the server, I get an error (error encountered while pushing to the remote repository... 500...). Obviously the gitlab server returns a 500 internal server error.
However when I open a command line from within team explorer and issue a 'git push', there are no errors and the push succeeds.

- Is there a difference between the team explorer push and the command line push?
- Is there a way to see what request team explorer sends to the gitlab server while pushing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On further inspection I found a difference between the GIT command line client and the builtin cliënt in visual studio. The latter uses TLS1.2 for the https session, whereas the command line uses TLS 1.0.

As it happens out private GITLAB server is situated behind a reverse proxy that has problems with TLS1.2 connections resulting in the weird behaviour (fetch & pull OK, no push).

Comment: What about Visual Studio 2017. Does it use TLS 1.2 too?

Comment: Yes, Just checked: TLS1.2

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017 it worked for us, even using the same repo. So It means something between these versions have change, even if both uses TLS 1.2

Comment: The real problem was with out (old) reverse proxy not handling  TLS1.2. Yours probably does?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you've diagnosed the problem yourself (nice sleuthing!)  But to answer your two direct questions:

There is a difference between the tooling built in to Visual Studio and the command line.  Visual Studio uses [libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2), which is a reimplementation of git as a linkable library.  It does not shell out to the command line at all to perform its work.

As a result, no, you cannot see the commands, as it is not actually running any.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I may take a look at the GITLAB logfiles to find out what's going wrong with the incoming request, but ultimately our reverse proxy will have to be fixed...

Comment: Yeah I'm curious about this - if you have more info I'd be interested in knowing how this is breaking down.  (Also, thanks for marking this as the answer but I think you should give that to yourself!  Mine is just random info about the product.)