# VS 2015 git push trouble

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I'm facing a problem with pushing branch using VS team explorer through https. But in command prompt "git push" works. It drives me crazy. I switched off firewall, but it did not help. Any doubts why it could happen?

```
Inner Exception:
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

Inner Exception:
    Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

    Inner Exception:
        A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Comment: Found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999042/git-push-not-working-in-visual-studio-2015, but it not very useful...

Comment: are you connecting directly to the Git server? what type of Git server is it? What's its version? Is it behind a proxy server or are you connecting directly? Is the certificate self-signed or fully trusted?

Comment: I use https://bitbucket.org/

Comment: And the rest of the questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error message and it turns out on VS Team Services that I hadn't given full permission for my team member (user with this issue) to write (push) their changes up on our project up on our Team Services account.

On VS Team Services; go to Control Panel > [your account] > [your project] > [your team].  Then select the Version Control tab and make sure 1) the user with an issue is added to the user list and 2) give permissions under in Access Control Summary choices.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was solved when I logged in to Windows with the same user as used in VS 2015 to pull/push. For some reason, no matter what I put into VS, it always used the current logged in user to connect to Git.