# How to check git commands VS2015 IDE invokes

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

We are experiencing an issue when using VS2015 to push commits to origin. Using the IDE the error is:

Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 ().

If we open the command line and invoke the push command, it works.

How to narrow down this issue to understand what is going on?

Thank you,

Comment: I tested in VS2017 and the push using IDE works fine. So it is something related to this version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git push not working in visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999042/git-push-not-working-in-visual-studio-2015)